# iOS simulator error Xcode 4.5

Tags: ios

So when I run simulator I get:

```
2013-01-28 13:35:38.271 Gas Index[79343:11303] -[Gas isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71a2260
2013-01-28 13:35:38.274 Gas Index[79343:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Gas isEqualToString:]: unrecognized   selector sent to instance 0x71a2260'
```

Here is my ViewController.m code. Any help is appreciated.
(I am a n00b to xcode)

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController {
    NSArray *gases;
}

@synthesize tableView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Gas *gas1 = [Gas new];
    gas1.name=@"Argon";
    gas1.desc=@"An Inert Gas,Ar";

    Gas *gas2 = [Gas new];
    gas2.name=@"Carbon Dioxide";
    gas2.desc=@"An Inert Gas, CO2";

    Gas *gas3 = [Gas new];
    gas3.name=@"Nitrogen";
    gas3.desc=@"An Inert Gas, N2";

    gases = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:gas1,gas2,gas3, nil];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [gases count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"GasCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [gases objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showGasDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        DetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.gas = [gases objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: Where do you set the `UIStoryboardSegue identifier`?

Comment: Your using the selector `isEqualToString` on Gas class or something named Gas I suspect this line `if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showGasDetail"]) {`

Comment: I set it in the storyboard. Click on the segue, then identifier. named it there

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode or iOS simulator. You should rephrase your question title and remove those tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [gases objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Split up that code:

```
Gas *gas = gases[indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = gas;
```

That is what you are trying to do. You can't assign a `Gas` object to a property that expects an `NSString`. You probably want this:

```
Gas *gas = gases[indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = gas.name;
```

Please note that when you run this in the debugger, you should see a stack trace showing you exactly what line this error is happening on.

Comment: Thank you, I am now getting a list. When I select an item it does show me what line the errors are on.